# Create a query using an enum

Tags: mysql

I have a table where one of the columns is an enum.

```
mysql> SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE [...];
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| COLUMN_TYPE                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| enum('1 DAY','1 WEEK','1 MONTH','3 MONTH','1 YEAR','2 YEAR') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to use these values in a subsequent query, something like this:

```
mysql> SELECT LPAD(MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)), 2, 0) A, 
              LPAD(MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)), 2, 0) B, 
              LPAD(MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 2, 0) C, 
              LPAD(MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), 2, 0) D, 
              LPAD(MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)), 2, 0) E, 
              YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) F, 
              YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) G, 
              YEAR (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) H, 
              YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) I, 
              YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)) J\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
A: 05
B: 05
C: 04
D: 05
E: 05
F: 2018
G: 2018
H: 2018
I: 2017
J: 2016
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I run these queries from a script and parsing the result of the first query and creating the second query isn't a massive problem. I was just wondering if someone could suggest a way to do this in one go.

Comment: You don't want an enum -- or not just an enum you want a linking table too. This would be easier if you weren't using a pretend database, but instead something like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want. `ENUM`s are inherently a unique textual representation, stored in a special way. You can't add a dynamic to them that makes them useful in any sense to an `INTERVAL`.

- MySQL doesn't really have `ENUM` types, it has more of a macro over intergers (a hack). [MDEV-4912](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4912), [MDEV-4913](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4913)
- MySQL [also lacks an interval type](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=831)

For these reasons, the best you can do is probably a lookup table.

See also,

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177075/2639